# How to check out tensorflow 2.15.0.post1

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, github

The `tensorflow` tags only has "`v2.15.0 --> Nov 15, 2023`", but `pypi` has "`tensorflow == 2.15.0.post1`"

https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/

```
tensorflow == 2.15.0.post1  Released: Dec 6, 2023
```

https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.15.0/

```
tensorflow == 2.15.0  Released: Nov 15, 2023
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags

```
v2.15.0 --> Nov 15, 2023
```

How to check out the source code version of "`tensorflow == 2.15.0.post1`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "post1" component of the version indicates a post-release, which is not new functionality, but just fixing a packaging error or a very minor correction in release notes or other documentation, so there is no new source code attached, it's the same version.

So you will not find the source code for that version, it's the same as 2.15. Below you see the official definition for a post-release:

> Post-releases
> Some projects use post-releases to address minor errors in a final release that do not affect the distributed software (for example, correcting an error in the release notes).

https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/version-specifiers/#post-release-separators